# What method is usually used to detect the time case?

Tags: c++, c, linux

There is a API for me to get some data,such as:

```
int API_func(pointer * data)
```

the return value is used to judge whether the function is done, and the data will be writen to the pointer address;
but if something wrong, the API_func may not get return ,The program may get stuck，so I need a timer to calculate the timer when call the API_func,and once the time over 30s ,I need to send a signal to GUI,so how can I do?
   I am a green hand ,so I want know how the Master do ？
My method is：

Thread_1: main Thread ,call API here,

Thread_2: timer Thread,include a timer function

when Thread_1 call API,send a msg(FIFO) to active the timer function at timer Thread,if the API cant return successed ,the timer at the Thread_2 will overtime ,then send a msg to GUI ?

is any better method ? thank a lot!
sorry,i am green hand in stackoverflow,so i dont how to express what I mean：
fake code:

```
 Thread_1:
    set_timer_flag_on(FILE *time_flag_1)
    API_func()
    Thread_2:
    if (1==check_timer_flag(FILE *time_flag_1))
    {
        timer_func(set_over_time);
    }
```

Comment: So you have a solution, which only lacks in not covering the time case. Please show that code; similar to a [mcve], apart from the fact that the error case is hard to demonstrate. I.e. show the code which handles the normal cases. Make a simplified example, using e.g. pseudo code `/* this is where an endless loop might occur */`.

Comment: i add some fake code ,maybe help to understand what i mean.and i want know is the method，not how to coding,thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can call `int API_func(pointer* data)` in a separate thread and signal the main thread by a *condition variable*.   For `int API_func(pointer* data)` you write a wrapper. an example is in **[How to implement timeout for function in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550730/how-to-implement-timeout-for-function-in-c)**

Comment: thank you very much！ I am a green hand ,and the way above is design by myself ,without anybody's help,so I afraid my way may be fool 。accoding to your advice ,use multi-thread is a normal way，i know how to do it ,thank you !