# How can I set timeout in C++?

Tags: c++, time, timeout

How can I set timeout in C++?

```
// -------------------------
system("..."); // this code run another C++ program using ubuntu terminal.
               // this code could be stuck in a loop
// -------------------------
```

How can I set some function or something to check whether another code took too long or not so that it can kill it.

Comment: please pick one language

Comment: It depends on the platform.

Comment: check it here! https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551227/11845630
Hope u got what you expect!

Comment: Yes, it does. Thx a lot!