# C++ function timeout wrapper

Tags: c++, timeout

Based on [How to implement timeout for function in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550730/how-to-implement-timeout-for-function-in-c), I wrote this wrapper:

```
template <typename t_time, typename t_function, typename... t_params>
inline std::conditional_t<
    // if 't_function' return type is 'void'
    std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<t_function, const bool &, t_params...>>,
    // the 'execute' wrapper will return 'bool', which will be 'true' if the
    // 'p_function' executes in less 'p_max_time', or 'false' otherwise
    bool,
    // else it will result a 'std::optional' with the return type of
    // 't_function', which will contain a value of that type, if the
    // 'p_function' executes in less 'p_max_time', or empty otherwise
    std::optional<std::invoke_result_t<t_function, const bool &, t_params...>>>
execute(t_time p_max_time, t_function &p_function, t_params &&... p_params) {
  std::mutex _mutex;
  std::condition_variable _cond;
  bool _timeout{false};

  typedef typename std::invoke_result_t<t_function, const bool &, t_params...>
      t_ret;

  if constexpr (std::is_void_v<t_ret>) {
    std::thread _th([&]() -> void {
      p_function(_timeout, std::forward<t_params>(p_params)...);
      _cond.notify_one();
    });

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lock{_mutex};
    if (_cond.wait_for(_lock, p_max_time) != std::cv_status::timeout) {
      _th.join();
      return true;
    }
    
    _timeout = true;
    _th.detach();
    return false;
  } else {
    t_ret _ret;

    std::thread _th([&]() -> void {
      _ret = p_function(_timeout, std::forward<t_params>(p_params)...);
      _cond.notify_one();
    });

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lock{_mutex};
    if (_cond.wait_for(_lock, p_max_time) != std::cv_status::timeout) {
      _th.join();
      return {std::move(_ret)};
    }
    _timeout = true;
    
    _th.detach();
    return {};
  }
}
```

Unlike the code in the answers for the question I referenced, I would not like to throw an exception in the `execute` wrapper. If `p_function` does not return, the wrapper will return a `bool`, `true` if `p_function` executed in at most `p_max_time`, `false` otherwise. If `p_function` returns `T`, the wrapper will return `std::optional<T>` which will have a value if `p_function` does not exceed `p_max_time`, or it will be empty otherwise.

The `const bool &` parameter required for `p_function` is used to inform `p_function` that its execution exceeded `p_max_time`, so `p_function` may stop its execution, though `execute` will not count on it.

Here is an example:

```
    auto _function = [](const bool &p_is_timeout, int &&p_i) -> void {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
      if (p_is_timeout) {
        std::cout << "timeout";
      } else {
        std::cout << "i = " << p_i << '\n';
      }
    };
    int _i{4};

    if (!async::execute(200ms, _function, std::move(_i))) {
      std::cout << "TIMEOUT!!\n";
    }
```

*So*, the problem is `_th.detach()` causes crash when I execute some test functions in a row. I if change it to `_th.join()`, the crash no longer occurs, but, obviously, the function that calls the wrapper has to wait for `p_function` to end, which is not desired.

How can I make `execute` detach `_th` thread, without causing crash?

Comment: The problem with this kind of approach is that it takes a function that you would expect to be synchronous (which has no possibility of a race condition) and make it asynchronous if it times out (it keeps running, now in parallel to the original code) and introduces the risk of a race condition. Unless the function is originally designed to be interruptible, or at the very least thread safe, it is not possible to implement this system reliably. Even when it is possible, it is usually unusable as it introduces detached threads which can't be synchronized. `deatch` is just about always an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda needs access to the local variables `_ret` and `cond` these don't exist after the end of `execute` so your code has undefined behaviour. Lambdas that capture by reference should only be used when the lambda has the same lifetime as the code that they're defined in.

You'd need to define your state variables in the heap so that they exist after the end of the function. For example you could use a `shared_ptr`:

```
template <typename Result>
struct state
{
  std::mutex _mutex;
  std::condition_variable _cond;
  Result _ret;
};
template <>
struct state<void>
{
  std::mutex _mutex;
  std::condition_variable _cond;
};

template <typename t_time, typename t_function, typename... t_params>
inline std::conditional_t<
    // if 't_function' return type is 'void'
    std::is_void_v<std::invoke_result_t<t_function, const bool &, t_params...>>,
    // the 'execute' wrapper will return 'bool', which will be 'true' if the
    // 'p_function' executes in less 'p_max_time', or 'false' otherwise
    bool,
    // else it will result a 'std::optional' with the return type of
    // 't_function', which will contain a value of that type, if the
    // 'p_function' executes in less 'p_max_time', or empty otherwise
    std::optional<std::invoke_result_t<t_function, const bool &, t_params...>>>
execute(t_time p_max_time, t_function &p_function, t_params &&... p_params) {
  typedef typename std::invoke_result_t<t_function, const bool &, t_params...>
      t_ret;
  auto _state = std::make_shared<state<t_ret>>();
  bool _timeout{false};

  if constexpr (std::is_void_v<t_ret>) {
    std::thread _th([&, _state]() -> void {
      p_function(_timeout, std::forward<t_params>(p_params)...);
      _state->_cond.notify_one();
    });

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lock{_state->_mutex};
    if (_state->_cond.wait_for(_lock, p_max_time) != std::cv_status::timeout) {
      _th.join();
      return true;
    }
    
    _timeout = true;
    _th.detach();
    return false;
  } else {
    std::thread _th([&, _state]() -> void {
      _state->_ret = p_function(_timeout, std::forward<t_params>(p_params)...);
      _state->_cond.notify_one();
    });

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lock{_state->_mutex};
    if (_state->_cond.wait_for(_lock, p_max_time) != std::cv_status::timeout) {
      _th.join();
      return {std::move(_state->_ret)};
    }
    _timeout = true;
    
    _th.detach();
    return {};
  }
}
```

Note for simplicity I've left in the capture of the function arguments and function by reference but you still need to ensure those references remain valid for as long as they're needed (e.g. if the timeout is short the function could exit before the target function executes or if the arguments are references then the invoked function can't use those references after the function exits).

If you have c++20 you might want to look into [std::jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread)

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers and suggestions, I came up with:

```
template <typename t_time, typename t_function, typename... t_params>
inline std::conditional_t<
    // if 't_function' return type is 'void'
    std::is_void_v<
        std::invoke_result_t<t_function, std::function<bool()>, t_params...>>,
    // the 'execute' wrapper will return 'bool', which will be 'true' if the
    // 'p_function' executes in less 'p_max_time', or 'false' otherwise
    bool,
    // else it will result a 'std::optional' with the return type of
    // 't_function', which will contain a value of that type, if the
    // 'p_function' executes in less 'p_max_time', or empty otherwise
    std::optional<
        std::invoke_result_t<t_function, std::function<bool()>, t_params...>>>
execute(t_time p_max_time, t_function &p_function, t_params &&... p_params) {
  std::mutex _mutex;
  std::condition_variable _cond;
  auto _timeout = std::make_shared<bool>(false);

  auto _is_timeout = [_timeout]() { return *_timeout; };

  typedef typename std::invoke_result_t<t_function, std::function<bool()>,
                                        t_params...>
      t_ret;

  if constexpr (std::is_void_v<t_ret>) {
    std::thread _th([&]() -> void {
      p_function(_is_timeout, std::forward<t_params>(p_params)...);
      _cond.notify_one();
    });

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lock{_mutex};
    if (_cond.wait_for(_lock, p_max_time) != std::cv_status::timeout) {
      _th.join();
      return true;
    }
    *_timeout = true;
    _th.join();
    return false;
  } else {
    t_ret _ret;

    std::thread _th([&]() -> void {
      _ret = p_function(_is_timeout, std::forward<t_params>(p_params)...);
      _cond.notify_one();
    });

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> _lock{_mutex};
    if (_cond.wait_for(_lock, p_max_time) != std::cv_status::timeout) {
      _th.join();
      return {std::move(_ret)};
    }
    *_timeout = true;
    _th.join();
    return {};
  }
}
```

And the example becomes:

```
    auto _function = [](std::function<bool()> p_timeout, int &&p_i) -> void {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
      if (p_timeout()) {
        std::cout << "timeout in work function\n";
      } else {
        std::cout << "i = " << p_i  << '\n';
      }
    };
    int _i{4};

    if (!execute(200ms, _function, std::move(_i))) {
       std::cout << "OK - timeout\n";
    }
    else {
       std::cout << "NOT OK - no timeout\n";
    }
```

I believe passing a `std::function<bool()>` to the work function (`p_function`) creates a good abstraction on how `execute` will control the timeout, and an easy way for `p_function` to check for it.

I also removed the `std::thread::detach()` calls.

Comment: I don't think you need `_timeout` to be a `shared_ptr`, probably should be `std::atomic` though